# cURL help with PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am playing with cURL, and I am having trouble getting it to work. I want the cURL script to post the data on that form so I can see the posted data in results.txt. Here is my form script and then my cURL script after. I changed the $url before posting here.

Edit: The problem is, it's not posting the data. I ran the cURL script, and checked the results.txt to find the post data "WORKS" and it's absent. Also, if it makes any difference, I am using DreamHost.

UPDATE: I GOT IT! Funny thing. I targeted to the page with the form instead of the page that processes the POST.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type"/>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="POST" name="TestForm" action="write.php">
      <p />
      Input anything: <input type="text" name="anything" value="Default"/> <br />
      <input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

write.php code source

```
    $stringData1 = $_POST["anything"];
    $myFile = "results.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fwrite($fh, $stringData1);
    fclose($fh);


?>
```

My cURL script code source:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.domain.com/submit/index.php";


$useragent="YahooSeeker-Testing/v3.9 (compatible; Mozilla 4.0; MSIE 5.5; http://search.yahoo.com/)";

$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "anything=WORKS");


$result= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 


print "<br/> test" . $result;

?>
```

Comment: It's not posting "WORKS"

Comment: can you var_dump($result); ? it would be better to check if curl return an error

Comment: @RageZ
It returned "bool(true)"

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with your response script? Try doing a `var_dump` of `$_POST`.

Comment: I really don't know. Am I suppose to put that in write.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing a string with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. Try using an array instead. Ex:
array( 'anything' => 'WORKS' );

Comment: What status code is returned?
echo curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

Comment: Warning: curl_getinfo(): 1 is not a valid cURL handle resource in domain.com/code-lab/curl.php on line 49

Line 49 is echo curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

Comment: add the line just after your curl_exec() but before curl_close()

Comment: After adding that, I see the number "200".